# Golang - Does AppEngine Datastore GetMulti() return invalid data when it returns a MultiError?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, error-handling, google-cloud-datastore

I am calling into the AppEngine Datastore to get data that may or may not be stored; I am not concerned with a multi error except in the case that all of the multi error entries return an error.

```
err := datastore.GetMulti(context, keys, data)
if err_entries, ok := err.(appengine.MultiError); ok {
    for _, err_entry := range err_entries {
        if err_entry == nil {
            return data, nil
        }
    }
}
return data, err
```

My question is whether the data returned, given that one err_entry of a multi error is nil, will contain false, empty, or corrupt data entries for keys that match an error in the multi error. It works as expected for now but I don't know what potential exceptions might come up or if this is horrendous for some idiomatic reason.

Answer (score 2):

Right from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#MultiError:

> MultiError is returned by batch operations when there are errors with particular elements.
>
> **Errors will be in a one-to-one correspondence with the input elements; successful elements will have a nil entry.**

It will never have data, each `i, err_entry` is either nil or an error linked to `data[i]`.

Comment: So an input will be made for every key input into the GetMulti? I guess what I am asking is whether output elements will be one to one with the error entries in MultiError

Comment: also whether their is any possibility of data or partial data being returned in the output for an entity whose key entry in the MultiError has an opaque error

Comment: @user41979 no, it will never have data, each `i, err_entry` is either nil or an error linked to `data[i]`.

Comment: Thanks, if you will update your answer with that info I'll accept it